# Document.queryselector not working on nested element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to target a nested 'a' tag in the HTML document but it's not getting recognized. What is wrong? Never had a problem before.

**Console log**

```
Uncaught TypeError: link is null
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">
           <div class="content">
            <h1>Blue Blood Fashion</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>is a high end prêt line of garments for an individual who is conscientious of his/her social position and status.</p>
            <a href="#">Enter Shop</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const bike = document.querySelector('.container .box .left');
const link = document.querySelector('.container .box .right .content a');

link.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    bike.classList.add('active');
})
```

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: Yeah just figured that. So dumb of me. Works now. Thanks :)